# Null reference exception while iterating over a list of StreamReader objects

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, nullreferenceexception, streamreader

I am making a simple Program which searches for a particular Name in a set of files.I have around 23 files to go through. To achieve this I am using  `StreamReader` class, therefore, to write less of code, I have made a

```
List<StreamReader> FileList = new List<StreamReader>();
```

list containing elements of type StreamReader and my plan is to iterate over the list and open each file:

```
foreach(StreamReader Element in FileList)
{
    while (!Element.EndOfStream)
    {
        // Code to process the file here.
    }
}
```

I have opened all of the streams in the FileList.The problem is that I am getting a

> Null Reference Exception

at the condition in the while loop.

Can anybody tell me what mistake I am doing here and why I am getting  this exception and what are the steps I can take to correct this problem?

Comment: warp your code inside `using` block and it will destroy any objects that are not cleaned up.

Comment: Well are there any null references in `FileList`? What *exactly* does the stack trace look like?

Comment: @Khushi can you please explain it in detail as I am new to C#

Comment: @Khushi: A `using` statement will make sure that `Dispose` is called. It won't actually destroy the objects.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ow my mistake. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @JonSkeet, There are no null reference in FileList

Comment: @Pratik good answer by 111WARLOCK111 and for more explanation http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader

Comment: @Pratik: Then I'd be *very* surprised if your `while` loop condition really showed a `NullReferenceException`. Again, please post the full stack trace. I suspect the problem isn't where you think it is.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't know how to see the stack trace, anyways  I'll try to post the stack trace as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As peoples described on above, Use the following way:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filename.txt"))
{
    ...
}
```

If you're trying to store files with their names on a list, I suggest you to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Files = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filename.txt"))
{
   string total = "";
   string line;
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      total += line;
   }
   Files.Add("filename.txt", line);
}
```

To access them:

```
Console.WriteLine("Filename.txt has: " + Files["filename.txt"]);
```

Or If you want to get the StreamReader It self not the file text, You can use:

```
Dictionary<string, StreamReader> Files = new Dictionary<string, StreamReader>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filename.txt"))
{
    Files.Add("filename.txt", sr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you tell why I was getting the null reference exception?

Comment: @Patrik It all depends on your StreamReaders code part, You might have closed the StreamReaders, It's not really a good Idea to keep a StreamReader (File) Open because It makes It on-Use and disallows any other applications to use It, Best way is to collect what you want from it (String) And then close, save the strings into memory. You shouldn't keep them open forever. To make sure Dispose(); is called the best way is to use the using format. Do the same way for StreamWriters also.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Since there are a lot of files, I have made two more functions which keep track of opening and closing of  the streams, so as soon as this function is called I call the close function, so no streams are left open

Comment: In case of claiming the `sr` you may not put it in a `using` block, because that renders the `StreamReader` useless.