# Null Reference Exception while iterating over StreamReader List

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I  want to find a particular string inside 40-50 long files. To do this , I used the following code:-

```
    foreach(StreamReader SR in FileList)
    {
       // Process the file
    }
    // File List contains initialized instances of StreamReader class
```

while doing so I am receiving

```
       null reference exception
```

although, when the

```
    FileList
```

contains only 1 element the code is working fine.   What can be the possible reason for this and how can it be corrected?
I have made a function like this, which initializes the files and adds them to FileList:

```
    public static void Initialize()
    {
      StreamReader File1 = new StreamReader("some valid path here",false, Encoding.UTF8) ; 
       FileList.Add(File1) ; 
       // Similarly for other files.
    }
```

the code inside the foreach loop is:-

```
    foreach( StreamReader SR in FileList)
    {
      while (!SR.EndOfStream)
      {
          Content = SR.ReadLine() ; 
          if(Content.Contains(Name))
          {
           Console.WriteLine("Found");
          }
       }
     } 
      // Content and Name are other string variable declared previously in the program
```

As some people pointed out that error might be caused by the variable Content, I want to clarify that this is not the case.

Comment: You have to add more code (declaration/population of FileList, what you are doing inside the foreach, etc.) to help us understand what is going on.

Comment: I  have added the details.

Comment: `StreamReader` implements `IDisposable`, you should initialise it within a `using` block

Comment: @Pratik at which line do you get the exception?

Comment: At the while loop line ie  while(!SR.EndOfStream)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610525/null-reference-exception-while-iterating-over-a-list-of-streamreader-objects) didnt solve your problem?

Comment: No, this did solve my problem,  but I don't want to use this approach because it's taking more time.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, it would be the most efficient and fastest solution

Comment: You come with a bad approach and with a poor explanation of your problem; you get help 5 persons proposing you solutions. The only reward for what you get is keep asking and once you get your ideas clear (= you were trying something with not too much point), you stop asking. Excellent behaviour. I will delete my answer right now (don't want to help people like this).

Answer (score 1):

Prabably because FileList is null and doesn't contains any elements. And of course this will throw exception. 
You should check that this is not null before to call foreach.
.. Or just init somewhere FileList with new before to fill it.

Comment: That's not the case, I have checked that it is not null, see the edit to the question.

Comment: Did you try to check if its null? because in this line foreach(StreamReader SR in FileList) exception can be thrown only if FileList is == to null

Comment: The FileList is not null, moreover if I open the files individually then it's opening.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Content` variable for null, because it's likely that `SR.EndOfStream` is not set correctly if `SR` is empty and not read to.

If it is possible, that there are null entries in the `FileList`, check `SR` for null also.

```
foreach( StreamReader SR in FileList)
{
  if(SR == null) continue;

  while (!SR.EndOfStream)
  {
      Content = SR.ReadLine() ; 
      if(Content != null && Content.Contains(Name))
      {
       Console.WriteLine("Found");
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `StreamReader`

> The next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached.

So you are reading pass the end of the stream which sets Content to null.

You should therefor change your looping logic

```
    while ((Content = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (Content.Contains(Name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found");
        }
    }
```

However I'd suggest to do it rather different

```
var paths = //set to a list of file paths
var findings = from path in paths
               from line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
               where line.Contains(name)
               select line
```

This will give you all the lines that contains the string in name

Comment: The exception is cause by either SR being null or Content being null and you claim that neither is null but those are the only objects in your code so you are contradicting your self

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice and safe method [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) (don't confuse with File.ReadAllLines)

It will not read the whole content of the file, but will load a line per call

```
foreach (string path in paths)
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        if (line.Contains(Name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```